# SBT test:compile is not satisfied by libraryDependencies in Test

Tags: scala, sbt

I have the snippet of test case below under `src/test/scala`:

```
package example.module

import utest._

object ModuleSpec extends TestSuite { ... }
```

... which compiles just fine with this snippet of `build.sbt` below:

```
val testDependencies: Seq[ModuleID] =
  Seq(
     "com.lihaoyi" %% "utest" % "0.6.5" % "test",
  )

def testSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] =
  Seq(
    libraryDependencies ++= testDependencies)

lazy val root =
  (project in file("."))
    .aggregate(subproject)

lazy val subproject =
  (project in file("subproject"))
    .settings(testSettings: _*)
```

My question is:

Why the test code does not compile anymore if I add `Test` axis to `libraryDependencies`, like shown below?

```
def testSettings: Seq[Setting[_]] =
    Seq(
      libraryDependencies in Test ++= testDependencies)
```

In more detail:

The line containing `import utest._` fails to compile, meaning that the dependency which is now declared as part of `libraryDependencies in Test` was ignored.

Argumentation:

Since I'm compiling a class under `src/main/test`, I would expect that `libraryDependencies in Test` would be the necessary and the sufficient piece of information in this case. In order words: I would not expect that a wider scope would be needed.

Comment: I've never understood why this is handled by `% "test"` (or `% Test`) rather than by `in Test`

Comment: @SethTisue :: ``% "test"`` means ``% "test->compile"`` which means that I'm declaring the fact that my ``subproject`` / ``src/test/scala`` depends on ``utest`` / ``src/main/scala``. However, the fact that it does not compile after I force ``Test`` axis tells me that ``% "test"`` must be populating settings somewhere else which I'm not aware of. Since ``Test extends Runtime, Compile``, then I can only suppose that ``Compile`` is the key here somehow.